# Capture edit mode through checking the standard tool bar

Tags: excel, vba, toolbar, findcontrol, editmode

I'm using this code to check if the standard toolbar is deactivated in the edit mode.

```
CommandBarControl oNewMenu = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl(1, 18, 1, True, True)

If (IsNull(oNewMenu)) Then

    MsgBox "Edit mode enabled"

End If
```

The FindControl function raise an error. Is there any conflict in the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused because the first statement will never compile.
Moreover when evaluating existence of an object you should use 'Is Nothing'
 instead of 'IsNull'. 
Anyway try this:

---

```
Const CTRL_NEW = 2520

Dim oControl As CommandBarControl

Set oControl = CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(Id:=CTRL_NEW)

If Not oControl Is Nothing Then ' Control New is present in Standard bar'
    MsgBox "Edit mode " & IIf(oControl.Enabled, "enabled", "disabled"), vbInformation
End If
```

Comment: in the following line what exactly oControl.Enable mean.Shoudn't the labels "enable" and "disable" be interchanged. 


MsgBox "Edit mode " & IIf(oControl.Enabled, "enabled", "disabled"), vbInformation .


Thank you...